# Quotes from Connes

Tags: homotopy-theory, smooth-manifolds

I found the following remark by Connes [HERE](http://books.google.com.sg/books?id=lBLoj_Gc9K4C&pg=PA17&lpg=PA17&dq=main+quality+of+the+homotopy+type+of+a+manifold+is+to+satisfy+Poincare+duality+not&source=bl&ots=2etHIOxkDQ&sig=ntikqw0LOGpiLg_sJF6ungG-A6c&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DicAVJLlEJaQuASU7YCgBQ&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=main%20quality%20of%20the%20homotopy%20type%20of%20a%20manifold%20is%20to%20satisfy%20Poincare%20duality%20not&f=false):
"the main quality of the homotopy type of a manifold is to satisfy Poincare duality not only in ordinary homology but in K-homology with the Fredholm module associated to the Dirac operator as the fundamental class".
Another time he said that:
"there is a non naive conception of the manifold: that it is a homotopy type plus Pontriagin classes".
As far as I know, Dirac operator is a tool which is present as long as your manifold is spin.
Could anybody explain to me how to understand these two remarks?

Comment: There is a notion of orientability of a manifold, more generally of any vector bundle, with respect to any (co)homology theory. Any manifold is orientable with respect to $H^*(,\mathbb Z/2)$. Only the orientable manifolds are orientable with respect to $H^*(,\mathbb Z)$. Only the $Spin^c$ manifolds are orientable w.r.t complex $K$-theory. Only the $Spin$ manifolds are orientable w.r.t real $K$-theory. The $String$ manifolds are orientable w.r.t the cohomology theory $tmf$. So the first quote has really nothing special about $K$-theory... and moreover is not valid for all manifolds.

Comment: I've added a citation for the first remark. Could not locate the second. Please have a look, and let us know if the context in the original source doesn't answer your first question. With regard to your second question, in dimension $\geq 5$, there are at most finitely many distinct smooth manifolds with the same homotopy type and Pontryagin classes.

Comment: The second quote, as far as I remember, comes from a lecture which I have in audio. Unfortunately I'm unable to find it now. Thank You for the reference to the first question: I will try to find a cited work of Sullivan. However, still I have a question: why it is the homotopy type in which we are interested? Has it something to do with the fact that in NC geometry we still don't have a notion of isomorphic spectral triples? Or maybe one is interested in homotopic equivalence just as one say that it is enough for two algebras to be Morita equivalent in order to represent the same NC space?